# Bash Loop iterate through each subdirectory

Tags: bash

Below script entering into only first directory of path /root/Archive/EKS/data and making zip file, its not switching into the second path /root/Incoming/data, can you please someone correct me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
 #!/bin/bash
   startdir=(
"/root/Archive/EKS/data"
"/root/Incoming/data"
)

 cd "$startdir" || exit

    for sub_dir in */ ; do
        zip -r "${sub_dir%/}.zip" "$sub_dir"
    done
```

Comment: You're only running `cd ...` once; you need to iterate over the entries in `startdir`, and do the `cd` and `zip` steps for each one.

Comment: Your `cd` command does not make sense, since `startdir` is an array. Which element of the array should it change to? I recommend putting a `set -x` in your script, so that you can debug this kind of problems by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assignment:

```
  startdir=(
"/root/Archive/EKS/data"
"/root/Incoming/data"
)
```

... sets `$startdir` to an *array* containing two pathnames. But this command:

```
cd "$startdir"
```

is only executed once, so it's not clear what you think it's going to do; automatically parallelize to process the whole array? Bash doesn't work that way. It just `cd`'s to the first element in the array, since that's what `$startdir` without an index expands to (the same as the more explicit `${startdir[0]}`.

What you need to do is *loop over* the array and repeat the commands for each element:

```
for dir in "${startdir[@]}"; do
(
  cd "$dir" || continue
  for subdir in */; do
    zip -r "${subdir%/}.zip" "$subdir"
  done
)
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You should loop through the directories and use a [subshell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) for the `cd`, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

startdir=(
  "/root/Archive/EKS/data"
  "/root/Incoming/data"
)

for dir in "${startdir[@]}"; do
 (
   cd "$dir" || exit
   for sub_dir in */ ; do
      zip -r "${sub_dir%/}.zip" "$sub_dir"
   done
 )
done
```

---

- Without the [subshell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) the `cd` would fail with an error message like, `no such file or directory` or something like that when it is done with the first directory.
- The outer `for` loop , loops through the top directories, while the inner one loops through the sub directories.
- Some more test needed, like if there are no subdirectories, what should happen?
- Consider using [nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob) shell option just before/above the second `for` loop.
- See [How Can I check if a directory is empty or not?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004)

Comment: Let me know if you have some questions.

Comment: Thanks lot i can able to see the script is entering into each directory and its creating zip.

Comment: @Gowmi, add an `echo` before the `zip` to see what it should do.

Answer (score -1):

#!/bin/bash

startdirs=(
"/root/Archive/EKS/data"
"/root/Incoming/data"
)

for startdir in "${startdirs[@]}"; do
cd "$startdir" || exit

```
for sub_dir in */; do
    zip -r "${sub_dir%/}.zip" "$sub_dir"
done
```

done

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).